# Python - delete a row based on condition from a pandas.core.series.Series after groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, series, drop

I have this pandas.core.series.Series after grouping by 2 columns `case` and `area`

| case | area |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2494 |
|  | 2 | 2323 |
| B | 1 | 59243 |
|  | 2 | 27125 |
|  | 3 | 14 |

I want to keep only areas that are in *case A* , that means the result should be like this:

| case | area |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2494 |
|  | 2 | 2323 |
| B | 1 | 59243 |
|  | 2 | 27125 |

I tried this code :

```
a = df['B'][~df['B'].index.isin(df['A'].index)].index
df['B'].drop(a)
```

And it worked, the output was :

[image]

But it didn't drop it in the dataframe, it still the same.

when I assign the result of droping, all the values became NaN

```
df['B'] = df['B'].drop(a)
```

[image]

what should I do ?

Comment: try adding `.dropna()`?

Comment: @mitoRibo I don't want to delete all areas in case B, I want to drop areas that doesn't exist in case A

Comment: thanks for explaining. I'd approach this by dropping the rows that you don't want and then grouping

Comment: @mitoRibo is it imposible to drop it after grouping ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is possible to drop after grouping, here's one way

```
import pandas
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)

ungroup_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'case':[
        'A','A','A','A','A','A',
        'A','A','A','A','A','A',
        'B','B','B','B','B','B',
        'B','B','B','B','B','B',
    ],
    'area':[
        1,2,1,2,1,2,
        1,2,1,2,1,2,
        1,2,3,1,2,3,
        1,2,3,1,2,3,
    ],
    'value': np.random.random(24),
})

df = ungroup_df.groupby(['case','area'])['value'].sum()
print(df)

#index into the multi-index to just the 'A' areas
#the ":" is saying any value at the first level (A or B)
#then the df.loc['A'].index is filtering to second level of index (area) that match A's
filt_df = df.loc[:,df.loc['A'].index]
print(filt_df)
```

Test df:

```
case  area
A     1       1.566114
      2       2.684593
B     1       1.983568
      2       1.806948
      3       2.079145
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Output after dropping

```
case  area
A     1       1.566114
      2       2.684593
B     1       1.983568
      2       1.806948
Name: value, dtype: float64
```